# Psr-4 deprecated Notice in laravel

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I am facing the below error on running the `composer dumpautoload`.

```
Deprecation Notice: Class App\Support\Dataviewer located in ./app/Traits/DataViewerTraits.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
```

Class `App\Support\Dataviewer` is where I am applying some logic for filters.

in my `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Support\\": "app/Support",
            "Traits\\": "app/Traits"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories",
            "app/Models"
        ]
    },
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deprecation Notice: Class Foo\Bar\Baz located in ./src/foo/bar/Baz.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010172/deprecation-notice-class-foo-bar-baz-located-in-src-foo-bar-baz-php-does-not)

Answer (score 2):

Ok was looking for the answer all over the place and stumbed upon the below issue link on github for composer : https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8465

the second last comment is what was needed for me to do. instead of adding the files in `psr-4 section`, I added it to `classmap` section, and voila ! its done :D

Answer (score 1):

First you're setting all inside `app/` as `App\\` namespace and then setting `app/Support` and `app\Traits` with a different namespace.

You should either move Support and Traits to the root folder or remove those namespaces from composer.json

Comment: Can you give me a code based answer itself. by default I never introduced the `"Support\\": "app/Support",
            "Traits\\": "app/Traits"` but as I got the warning, I did the above but still the issue is not solved :(