# Error with autoloading. Class does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping

Tags: php, autoload, psr-4, craftcms

This Error happens when update to composer 2 from composer 1

Class moduleNema\twigExtensions\NemaTwigExtension located in ./modules/moduleNema/twigExtensions/NemaTwigExtensions.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.

Folders:

```
    modules
      -> modulesNema
         -> controllers

         -> services
            -> Dark.php
            -> Rent.php

         -> twigExtensions
            -> NemaTwigExtensions.php

         -> Module.php

      -> Module.php
```

NemaTwigExtensions.php:

```
<?php
namespace moduleNema\twigExtensions;

use moduleNema\services\Dark;
use moduleNema\services\Rent;

class NemaTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension implements \Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface
{
    public function getGlobals()
    {
        return array(
            'nema' => array(
                'dark' => new Dark(),
                'rent' => new Rent()
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Module.php

```
<?PHP

   

    namespace moduleNema;

       use moduleNema\twigExtensions\NemaTwigExtension as NemaTwigExtension;

       use Craft;
 

    use craft\services\Elements;


 

    use yii\base\Event;


 class Module extends \yii\base\Module
  {
      public function init()
      {
          parent::init();

          Event::on(Elements::class, Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT, function( Event 
           $event ) {
        
           });
        
            if ( Craft::$app->request->getIsSiteRequest() ) {
               // Add in our Twig extension
               $extension = new NemaTwigExtension();
               Craft::$app->view->registerTwigExtension($extension);
            }        
         }
      }
```

on composer:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
          "modules\\": "modules/",
          "moduleNema\\": "modules/moduleNema"
        },
      },
```

I try all kinds of stuff, and still can solve my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rename all folders like this:

```
modules

      -> ModulesNema
         -> Controllers

         -> Services
            -> Dark.php
            -> Rent.php

         -> TwigExtensions
            -> NemaTwigExtensions.php

         -> Module.php

      -> Module.php
```

Then change all namespace like

```
use Modules\ModuleNema\TwigExtensions\NemaTwigExtensions;
use Modules\ModuleNema\Services\Dark;
use Modules\ModuleNema\Services\Rent;
```

on composer:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
          "Modules\\": "modules/",
          "ModuleNema\\": "modules/ModuleNema"
        },
      },
```

and run

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

now all it's working with composer 2

Comment: What solved the problem? Could you elaborate a little more and make your answer more useful to others? If it was simply a typo or just not going to be helpful consider retracting question.

Comment: I just rename all folders and make them capitalize. Do the same with the namespace and all psr-4 errors disappear. So my error was that all folders and subfolders were in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Just like [Yivi answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010172/class-foo-bar-baz-located-in-foo-bar-utility-baz-php-does-not-comply-with-psr)

This problem may happen for many reasons, you should check the **Path Case**, **File name and Class name or Namespace differences** and **Nested namespaces and missing declaration**

Comment: Do you think my problem are the namespace?

Comment: Try changing the path: moduleNema\twigExtensions\NemaTwigExtension to ModuleNema\TwigExtensions\NemaTwigExtension

Comment: Deprecation Notice: Class ModuleNema\TwigExtensions\NemaTwigExtension located in ./modules/ModuleNema/TwigExtensions/NemaTwigExtensions.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard

Comment: still same error, is crazy

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace MVC\core;

class app{

    private $controller = 'home';
    private $method = 'index';
    private $params = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->url();
        $this->render();
    }


    private function url(){
        
        if(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])){
            $url =  explode("/",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

            // this controller
            $this->controller = isset($url[0]) ? $url[0]."controller" : "homecontroller"; 
            // this method 
            $this->method = isset($url[1]) ? $url[1] : "index";
            unset($url[0],$url[1]);
            // this params
            $this->params = array_values($url); 
        }else{
            $this->controller = 'homecontroller';
            $this->method = 'index';
        }
    }

    private function render(){ 
        $controller = "MVC\controllers\\".$this->controller;
         if(class_exists($controller)){
            
            $controller = new $controller;

            if(method_exists($controller,$this->method)){
                
                
                call_user_func_array([$controller,$this->method],$this->params);


            }else{
                echo 'method not exist';
            }
            
         }else{
             echo 'class nt exist';
         }   
    }


}
```

Comment: Please delete or improve this answer.